# Can we parametrise a CSS style?

Tags: css, parameters

I am displaying a clean percentage background thanks to this CSS code:

```
.percent {
   background: linear-gradient(to left,  #FFBFBF 10%, #9BF7BF 10%) no-repeat;
   background-position-y: 45%;
   background-size: 100% 21px;
}
```

My question is: **can I parametrised somehow the percentage (10% here) from the HTML?** Ideally it could look like  `<td class="percent(10)">`

The only solution I can think of is to generate 100 `.percent` CSS styles and invoke the proper one from HTML like `<td class="percent10">` or `<td class="percent87">` but this is pretty ugly, isn't it?

For now the rendering looks like that:

[image: CSS Percentage]

Comment: That's typically done by applying `style="width: 87%"` to the progress element itself...

Comment: But the background is made of 2 colors here, green and pink, how to apply the width 87% to a half background, and 100%-87% to the other half?

Comment: Pink 100% wide element, on top of that a green element with varying percentage, on top of that an element with the text "... %"...

Comment: I am pretty newbie with CSS, a piece of working code would be very welcome, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've implemented the *ugly* solution. Yet considering the number of cells can be very large, I don't think we can do better in terms of number of characters in HTML and CSS documents.

```
/* Generates somehow these 101 lines */
.pct0 { background: linear-gradient(to right, #9BF7BF 0%, #FFBFBF 0%); } 
.pct1 { background: linear-gradient(to right, #9BF7BF 1%, #FFBFBF 1%); } 
(...)
.pct100 { background: linear-gradient(to right, #9BF7BF 100%, #FFBFBF 100%); } 

/* This don't work if rules below comes before the rules above */
.pct0,.pct1, (...) , pct100
{ 
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 95% 18px;
  text-align: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML uses styles `<td class="pct0">` `<td class="pct1">`, ... `<td class="pct100">`

[image: CSS percentage display]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way how to conceptually approach this:

```
<div style="position: relative; background: #FFBFBF; width: 200px; height: 25px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: #9BF7BF; width: 87%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">87%</div>
</div>
```

The "background" div (the outermost one) has the pink color; on top of that you put a green div whose `width` you vary, and on top of that you write your percentage as text.

Comment: Thanks! But I can have many cells concerned (like tens of thousands) doing so would work but would make the size of the HTML burst. At least the ugly solution I propose is O(100) and not O(#percentage cells)

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that this is an actual limitation...?

Comment: No, yet the 'ugly' solution proposed is nicer :)